# Using Spring ResourceServlet to serve multiple resources simultaneously

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

The JavaDoc for the ResourceServlet states that it can return a list of resources. But examples of this usage pattern seem to be sparse at best.

We have a web.xml with the following:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resource</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resource</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/combo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When we make a request to url along the lines of:
http://localhost:8080/app/combo?resource=js/file1.js;js/file2.js

We only seem to get file1 in the response.

What would a proper configuration be for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in our case turned out to be that the application used the mvc:resource utility to handle versioning of the static files. The backend of the mvc:resource utility will not respond to multiple files properly as Bosho noted, and I was aware of too from looking at the source.

Answer (score 2):

The `ResourceServlet` has been deprecated in favour of using `<mvc:resources />` However, it doesn't handle multiple resources. You'd have to make your own controller to do that.

As for the `ResourceServlet`, the delimiters used in the code are `,; \t\n` - any of them should work.

Comment: I saw that and read the source code, if you look at the above example you will see we are using a semi-colon as a delimiter. Unfortunately, it only seems to return the first resource.

Comment: could you step through the spring code with a debugger? I don't see a reason to fail