# create servlet url-pattern with "/"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I've created servlet named MainContent. and I have such mapping

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>MainContent</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MainContent</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ge.test.servlet.MainContent</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainContent</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so, when I go to the link:
 **//localhost:8080/MyAppl/main** I enter into the  servlets doGet() method. Then  I create  RequestDispatcher forward  to the  index.jsp.

**everything works!**

```
RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp?language="+ lang);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**everything works!**

**Question:**

Now I need to change  url-pattern. I need something like that-:when I enter to the  **localhost:8080/MyAppl/** I need to be redirected to my servlet. 
So I create something like that:

`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

**ok, it works!** I'm redirected to the servlet. **but** something wrong happend here. when  Servlet created  RequestDispatcher forward  , there was no  images and css in my index.jsp.
when I see in the firebug console, I've seen that errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/font/font_big.css". localhost/:15
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/IMG/company.gif".
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: The problem you are encountering is that all your resource paths start with /.  You need to add something to handle resources (spring had a resource servlet for that) and using a common URL pattern to identify the resources (for example, all resources start with "/Resourcde") then adding the resource handler servlet mapping before the "/" mapping in your web.xml file

Comment: this demonstrates the spring solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047150/using-spring-resourceservlet-to-serve-multiple-resources-simultaneously

Comment: I dont use Spring. I use only servlets and JSP. can you give me an example, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like @DwB pointed, '/' context is problematic URL pattern and it causes your problem.

Use

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

instead. It is "the servlet 3.0 way" to do this.

**Sources**

[1] http://www.coderanch.com/t/366340/Servlets/java/servlet-mapping-url-pattern

[2] [How can I map a "root" Servlet so that other scripts are still runnable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030302/how-can-i-map-a-root-servlet-so-that-other-scripts-are-still-runnable)

Comment: So, use empty as the special url pattern.