# App engine default page to be servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have App engine application, with that servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Authorization</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>x.y.z.Authorization</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Authorization</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pattern</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

everything works.
servlet invokes with this pattern **http ://localhost/pattern**

now I want to create AutorizationServlet default page. I need to invoke that servlet with this pattern:

**http ://localhost**

if I write `<url-pattern></url-pattern>` I have **AppEngineConfigException:**

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Comment: it's another one. It may cause another problem. see that question: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408805/create-servlet-url-pattern-with)

Comment: @DSTH or you can set your default page in your web.xml and put your AutorizationServlet there..